# Css :hover removes all other styles from parent container

Tags: css

As I have demonstrated in [this pen](http://codepen.io/Awesomennjawarrior/pen/ygQXZz), I am having a problem with the hover style of a link taking away the styles of the div it is in. The problem goes away, though, if I change the style on the `#div div {background-color:blue; }` to  `div {background-color:blue; }`.

Comment: Because there isn't a `div` inside `#div` ...

Comment: So, what actually you want?

Comment: Is it something like this what you want: http://codepen.io/ayandey/pen/egQEpj

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the second `div` in your CSS. Your problem is caused by the `#div div` which in CSS, actually means the div **INSIDE** the parent div. Right now you don't have that.

```css
#div {
  background-color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <a>Yo!</a>
</div>
```